# How to calculate this limit related to continued fractions?

Tags: limits, number-theory, continued-fractions

Given that $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n/q_n=\sqrt{2}$, how to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n|p_n-\sqrt{2}q_n|$?

Here, $p_n$ and $q_n$ are defined by the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}$, and $p_n=a_np_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$ and $q_n=a_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}$, where $a_n$ is the $n$-th number in the continued fraction representation $\sqrt{2}=[1,2,2,\cdots]$.

I did a little bit of calculation for the first few terms and found out that the result should be $\sqrt{2}/4$, but I cannot figure out how to prove this result. It seems that ordinary single variable or multivariable approaches do not work in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Unsure if this comment is *off-point*.  If so, please disregard.  It looks like you are investigating continued fractions and the pell equation.  It also looks like you are trying to *re-invent the wheel*, and discover associated basic results yourself rather than consulting literature on the subject.  If so, I advise against it.  If your interest is in fact in continued fractions &/or the pell equation, then I suggest [this pdf](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf) : (at least chapter one anway).  ...see next comment

Comment: I also recommend [this pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf) in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's easy to solve the recurrences in closed form:
\begin{align}
p_n&=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}+(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}}{2}
\\q_n&=\frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{n+1}-(1-\sqrt2)^{n+1}}{2\sqrt2}
\end{align}
(which makes $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}q_n\big|p_n-q_n\sqrt2\big|=\frac1{2\sqrt2}$ obvious).